Dynamic Adobe Signer
I have a document with Adobe Sign tags for signatures.
Adobe uses tags like {{Sig_es_:signer1:signature}} for signers.
In my document, I have two signers:

User A: {{Sig_es_:signer1:signature}}
User B: {{Sig_es_:signer2:signature}}

I've created a custom component that lets me choose the order of signers dynamically using checkboxes.
For example, at runtime, I might select User A as signer 2 and User B as signer 1. However, Adobe Sign then directs User B to sign where User A was supposed to.
Instead of using signer1 and signer2 tags, can we use unique text as anchor text like in DocuSign?
For instance, can we map users to signatures using unique text like a Salesforce username?
Note: We are sending the document using integration.
We trierd to Signer1 tag with custom unique text.
